# Android Nougat: Bottom layout hides behind Nexus navigation buttons when using ViewPager

Tags: android, android-7.0-nougat

While my application has been working fine on Android 4.3 - Android 6, on Android 7 the same design is not working anymore.

What should happen:

[image]

What actually happens on Nougat:

[image]

If the TextView has a margin of its height, it would show as expected on Nougat, however it wouldn't be on the bottom pre-Nougat.

**This only occurs if this fragment is in a ViewPager**. Otherwise it shows just fine.

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginBottom="48dp">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="CONTENTS HERE"/>
    </ScrollView>
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:text="YOU CANNOT SEE ME"/>
</FrameLayout>
```

Note: It does not happen on Android Studio's design view, only on the real device. This screenshots are a replica of what happens on a real device.

Anyone has an idea?

Comment: I had same problem, putting `fitsSytemWindow=true` in manifest for this particular activity worked for me

Comment: @MohammedAtif You mean setting `fitsSystemWindows=true` for the activity root view? Did not work for me.

Comment: Nope, you must do it in manifest.

Comment: @MohammedAtif I do not see how I can do that in the manifest, can you elaborate on which tag does this apply?

Comment: Yea, just found out that this is not possible in SDK 24, https://medium.com/google-developers/why-would-i-want-to-fitssystemwindows-4e26d9ce1eec#.b6ge6njiw i found this article for the same, might be helpful

Answer (score 0):

Found a fix.

I was using

```
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/vpTabs"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    android:background="@android:color/white" />
```

By removing the layout behavior, it was fixed.

```
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/vpTabs"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/white" />
```